# What type of throwable error is appropriate to use for this situation?

Tags: c#, error-handling, throw

I finished working on a basic AI and it moves using a case switch; either 0 (illegal move), 1 and 2 (legal moves). The way I coded the AI is so that the value of the case switch **should** never be 0. To be safe, I coded what it should do as followed:

```
if(csZetType > 0) //csZetType is the value for the switchcase, this can't be anything else
                  //than 0, 1 or 2 unless hardcoded.
    {
        Move();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Impossible Move of AI", "BUG detected!");
        throw new NotImplementedException(); //Only one I know
    }
```

The `NotImplementedException()` is the only version I know. I'm currently using it but I know this is not the right one.  Which one do I need for this situation?

*the method Move exists out of a proper switch case by the way, don't worry.*

Comment: Exceptions only matter in how you're going to handle them.  Use whatever is most appropriate to your situation.

Comment: @theIncorrigible I know, but I want the proper error for it, since it's not that it is not implemented. There is probably some form of throwable error used to highlight bugs instead of something not implemented.

Comment: That's not really what this site is for, however.  If you want opinions, you might want to check out codereview.

Comment: If the site is not for assistance when it comes to programming/code, I don't know what this site is for...

Comment: What @TheIncorrigible1 meant was that opinionated questions are not normally welcomed here. However, what about `InvalidOperationException`? "The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state."

Comment: Apologies, quite grumpy today. Anyways, That seems to be an option I can use. Thank you.

Comment: If you type  `throw new` + space and begin typing "exception", Intellisense will list all the predefined exceptions available. Unless you want to [create your own exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Exception)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2#Custom)) and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if it reaches to `else` block then it looks like a invalid operation been tried to performed. Then it would be a good case for [`InvalidOperationException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) but that again a suggestive answer.